# Does the Apollo `subscribeToMore` variables have to match the initial query?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Does the Apollo `subscribeToMore` variables have to match the initial query? For example, if my initial query is

```js
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(INBOX)
```

where the variable is from the id verified in the server(not sent from the client)

```js
     async inbox(parent, args, { request, prisma }, info) {
        const id = await getUserId(request)
        if (!user.email) {
            throw new Error('You must be logged in!')
        }
        return prisma.query.user({
            where: {
                id,
            }
        },info)
     }
```

And if the subscription resolver is like the following:

```js
   newInbox: {
        subscribe: (parent, args, { pubsub }, info) => pubsub.asyncIterator(PUBSUB_NEW_INBOX)
    },
```

would the subscription data be sent to every client in the database since the subscription itself doesn't have the filtering variable or would it recognize that the initial query already had a variable of its own?

In other words, it is necessary to do something like the following?

```js
 newInbox: {
        subscribe: withFilter(
            (parent, args, { pubsub }, info) => pubsub.asyncIterator(PUBSUB_NEW_INBOX),
            (payload, variables) => payload.newInbox.id === variables.id
        )
    },
```

by sending a variable from the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your filters must be **exactly the same**. 
The reason for this is that the cache is populated with the exact query as the key for this response.

So if you ask for `{queryX, limit:2}` this is cached as a different query than `{queryX, limit:100}`.

You can actually see this for yourself in the cache if you're using Apollo Dev Tools:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is very informative. What is the key for the response in the absence of the filter? Also, this means the client will have to send a redundant variable, which in my example the `id`, for the sole purpose of subscription even though it's not required in the initial query, correct?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. I'd assume it's an empty options object. But you should be able to see that in the Apollo dev tools. No, that is incorrect, my screenshot is from to separate queries. Sorry that's confusing.